# Primitive of a composite function

Tags: real-analysis, indefinite-integrals, function-and-relation-composition

I'm reading Zorich, Mathematical Analysis I, and I found a not clear step in the paragraph on Primitives.
The particular sentence is shown below (adapted).

*From the definition of primitive of a function on an interval, and from the properties of differentiation, the following relation holds:
$$\int (f\circ \phi)(t)\phi '(t)\mathrm{d}t=(F\circ \phi)(t)+c$$
where $F$ is the primitive of $f$ on an interval $I\subset\mathbb{R}$, and $\phi:I_t\subset\mathbb{R} \to I_x\subset I$ is a function $C^{(1)}(I_t)$.*

I can not understand why it is necessary that $\phi '(t)$ has to be continuous in $I_t$, what would be wrong if it were not? I can not see the problem in that case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the notation $\int g(t)\,dt = G(t), t\in I,$ means simply that $G'(t)=g(t),t\in I,$ you are correct. You might have problems with

$$\int_a^b (f\circ \phi)(t)\phi'(t)\,dt = (F\circ \phi)(b)-(F\circ \phi)(a)),$$ however. Now that I think about it, you could have problems with that even with Zorich's formulation.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.